# What is this insect in winter?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I came across a bunch of these tiny ball-pen-sized insects that (to me) look like they belong to the beetle family. They are all dead but I do remember seeing it once flying in my apartment. They are as small as fruit flies.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you're right that it's a beetle, but the picture quality (which I realize you may not be able to improve) will likely forbid anyone going any deeper than that.

Comment: @user please put more effort into your posts regarding grammar, capitalization, and spelling. This is a site intended for professionals, not yahoo answers. They will get downvoted. Regarding your question: I agree with Arther -- looks like a beetle, but the photo quality makes an informed ID rather difficult

Comment: "This is a site intended for professionals..." Has Stack Exchange implemented a new policy recently? This site is not "intended" for any specific, named group of people. The site is open to everyone, and strives to be open and *welcoming* to all, *especially new contributors*.

Comment: @theforestecologist That wasn't very nice or welcoming. Not everyone here is a native English speaker. If you have an issue with someone's grammar/spelling/punctuation, feel free to edit it or ask for clarification (I see you did edit this one).

Comment: @L.B. misspelling (and not correcting) words while using a built-in spell-checker and not capitalizing words like "I" are not an ESL issue; they're indicative of a rushed post or a lack of professionalism. Grammar is less necessary, but I did not tell the OP to write perfectly -- rather, I requested politely that they put adequate time/effort into writing a more professional post (as [is suggested by our help section](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)).

Comment: @theforestecologist Not here to argue. However, issues like not capitalizing "I" actually can be ESL issues and especially with a phone's autocorrect, that is a very common issue. I'm not defending making lots of mistakes. I am defending the person because we don't know them personally and they are asking a legit question and simply made mistakes.

Comment: @uhoh it *is* intended for a specific group. From our [tour page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tour): "*Biology Stack Exchange is a question and answer site **for biology researchers, academics, and students***". Of course, anyone is welcome to use this site & we strive to make that experience helpful as much as we can. However, we do have standards (see [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) & [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error)), & posters are expected to meet those standards.Voting/commenting are our tools for promoting adherence.

Comment: @L.B. sure we don't know anybody personally, which is why we have a code of conduct. And that's why I asked *politely* (see the use of "please"), and then followed-up by editing to show them their mistakes. It's a learning process, but one which requires pointing out a misstep. We can't just pretend everything is ok.

Comment: @theforestecologist okay that works because anyone who wants to learn can be considered a student. So we can agree that "This is a site intended for professionals..." is probably not the right way to paraphrase?

Comment: @uhoh professional in regards to conduct and style, not in regards to level of expertise. In other words, I was referring to [*professionalism*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/professionalism)

Comment: @theforestecologist yep that works.